# Is there anyway to remove db entry if saved object is not present in updated client request?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, postgresql, hibernate

If, for example, the db entry is created with two objects from an array of request payload.

```
Request : {"users":[{"identifier":"abctest","name":"uan"},{"identifier":"deftest","name":"Aj"}]}

Response : {"users":[{"id":182,"identifier":"abctest","name":"uan"},{"id":301,"identifier":"deftest","name":"Aj"}]}
```

Then delete one object of that array from frontend and try to send request with only one object in array instead of two of request payload.

```
Updated Request : {"users":[{"id":182,"identifier":"abctest","name":"uan"}]}

Response :  {"users":[{"id":182,"identifier":"abctest","name":"uan"},{"id":301,"identifier":"deftest","name":"Aj"}]}

Expected response : {"users":[{"id":182,"identifier":"abctest","name":"uan"}]}
```

How to delete that one object which saved in db but not present in request payload?

Sorry if I am missing anything, I am new to Java.

Comment: Code snippets, request payload structure would help answering the question, please edit the question and add them. Also, Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it, depending on your requirement:

- Delete all the entry in table and insert new users from payload.
- Create a new table mapping user-ids and admin-id(or the master user who has send the request to create these users)

So now every time a particular user/admin sends the request to create user you have to only delete from mapping table based on this requester's id and insert new

Comment: Thank you for answer Rahul. It would be helpful if  you can provide some code sample to understand the implementation ?